# How to check if property is static in String BeanWrapper PropertyDescriptor?

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-bean

I want to print all instance properties of an object.

Unfortunately the class `MyObject` contains static method "setThird", which matches naming pattern for properties. And even though the field "third" is private and has no getter it is being captured as a property by `BeanWrapperImpl`.

So the following code prints:

```
first = true
second = abc
third = not readable
```

**How to exclude the property "third" and print only instance properties?**

*Code:*

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
var wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);

Stream.of(wrapper.getPropertyDescriptors())
      .forEach(p -> {
        final String name = p.getName();
        final Object value =
            wrapper.isReadableProperty(name)
          ? wrapper.getPropertyValue(name) 
          : "not readable";

        println(name + " = " + value);
      });

// ---

class MyObject {
    private static String third = "i am static";

    public String getSecond(){return "abc";}
    public boolean getFirst(){return true;}

    // presence of this method affects availability of property "third"
    public static void setThird(String x){
      // nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you can get the info another way but `Modifier.isStatic(p.getWriteMethod().getModifiers())` should return it (of course you'd need the null check on the write method first).

Comment: Having a deeper look the situation is like this: you're using `BeanWrapperImpl` which internally uses `ExtendedBeanInfoFactory` to wrap introspection results with `ExtendedBeanInfo`. That class specifically detects non-standard setters like those that have a return value or _static_ setters. If you don't want those try `Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyObject.class).getPropertyDescriptors();` instead.